# Вывод каждой категории и их товаров с новой строки в WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

На главной странице магазина я использую код, который выводит название категорий с товарами такого вида:

Категория 1

Продукт 1 Продукт 2 Продукт 3

Категория 2

Продукт 1 Продукт 2 Продукт 3

Этот код я добавил в файл archive-product.php дочерней темы:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );

/**
* Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
* @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
* @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
    * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
    *
    * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
    * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {

            /* Start my loop section */
            foreach( get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ) ) as $category ) :
                $products_loop = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',

                    'showposts' => -1,

                    'tax_query' => array_merge( array(
                        'relation'  => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'terms'    => array( $category->term_id ),
                            'field'   => 'term_id'
                        )
                    ), WC()->query->get_tax_query() ),

                    'meta_query' => array_merge( array(

                    // You can optionally add extra meta queries here

                ), WC()->query->get_meta_query() )
            ) );

            ?>                      

            <h2 data-link="<?php echo get_term_link( (int) $category->term_id, 'product_cat' ); ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>

            <?php
                while ( $products_loop->have_posts() ) {
                    $products_loop->the_post();
                    /**
                    * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                    *
                    * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                    */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endforeach;
            /* End my loop section */

    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
    * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
    * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
    *
    * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}

/**
* Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

/**
* Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer( 'shop' );
```

Но к сожалению, категории и продукты не выводятся как надо. Категории идут в одну строку, а должны выводится с новой строки.

Это проблема с кодом в файле или со стилями? Как это можно исправить? Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внешний вид можно поправить с помощью CSS. Но у вас невалидная разметка т.к. в ul дочерний елемент h2.

```
.layout-standard h2 {
    clear: both;
}
```

Вам нужно перенести `woocommerce_product_loop_start` под h2. А `woocommerce_product_loop_end` после цикла.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Перенес start и end как вы сказали, все заработало. Огромное спасибо за помощь!